# facebook graph data - create like button

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

hi i want to display the facebook news feed of my fb-page on my website.

I used the graph.facebook.com to successfully get my posts. json sample below. In my php script i can loop through the data and display the messages. so far everything is fine.

what i need to know is - how can i create a like button for every post on my website? (i think i need to create a link which contains the post id?)

```
    {
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "some ids here",
      "name": "Timeline Photos",
      "message": "she rocks!
... blabla
  }
}
```

Comment: You can not use the default Facebook Like Button plugin to like an individual post. You would need to make users login to your app, so that you can create a like via API.

Comment: hi thank you - ok then i will stick only with the share button.. i use https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=(and-here-the-link-to-the-facebook-post)